# Differentiation of $v(a)=18^2 \cdot a$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{d(v)}{da}=  \frac{d}{da} \left( 18^2 a+ 12a^2 -144a \right).$$

I get the answer as $0$ but it is given $18^2$ as answer for only the first term I am talking about.

Not getting why the constant is not differentiated?

Comment: $\dfrac d {dx} (cx)=c$

Comment: We often say that "differentiation is linear"
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left( b f(x) + c  g(x)\right) = b \frac{d}{dx} f(x) + c \frac{d}{dx}g(x).  $$
Where $b$ and $c$ are constant in terms of $x$.

Comment: In your case $\frac{d}{da} 18^2 a =18^2 \frac{d }{da}a =18^2 \frac{d a}{da} = 18^2 \cdot 1$. We see that constants just pass through differentiation unaffected.

Comment: But in case of 2nd differentiation, they will too become zero.

Comment: Well this too can be explained with the power rule $3=3\cdot 1= 3x^0$ so if we differentiate a constant, we bring a zero down which gives us $ \frac{d}{dx} 3 x^0= 3 \frac{d}{dx}x^0= 3\cdot 0 x^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: Such a rule would be more formally explained using the concept of "limit", but I do not think you are there yet.

Comment: Yes. I am not there.thnx though

Comment: For now just remember that constants slide through, unless there is just a constant, then its derivative is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule:

$\dfrac {d (u v)} {d a} = u \dfrac {dv} {da} + v \dfrac {du} {da}$

In this case, $u = 18^2$ and $v = a$.

So you get $18^2 \times \dfrac {da} {da} + a \dfrac {d (18^2)} {da}$.

This of course works out to $18^2 \times 1 + a \times 0$.